# Turning a Tableau Calculation into a SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tableau-api

I am trying to validate a Tableau value through writing a SQL query but I do not feel like I understand the calculation to its fullest

The calculation is

```
IF      {   FIXED   Account ,  MonthYear :   MAX([type])   } = 'Upgrade' THEN    'Upgrade'
ELSE    {   FIXED   Account ,  MonthYear  :   MAX(plan)   }
END
```

SQL query is

```
SELECT 
    ACCOUNT, 
    CASE 
       WHEN MAX(type) = 'Upgrade' 
          THEN 'Upgrade'
          ELSE MAX(plan) 
    END AS plan,
    MonthYear,
    USAGE
FROM  
    table
GROUP BY 
    Account, monthyear
```

The number is not aligning up with the data, so I just want to make sure I am understanding completely what this tableau calculation is doing

Answer (score 1):

The query doesn't quite make sense.  Do you intend this?

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, 
       (CASE WHEN MAX(type) = 'Upgrade' then 'Upgrade'
             ELSE MAX(plan)
        END) as plan,
       MonthYear
FROM table
Group by Account, MonthYear
```